# how do I find a # with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, twitter-feed

I recently built a small app for my site that allows my users to display their tweets.
I am wondering if their is a way with jQuery or Javascript to detect or find stuff like hashtags and http://'s ?

A simple example of a sentence might be:

```
The quick #brown fox jumps over the #lazy dog
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might give [twitter-text-js](https://github.com/bcherry/twitter-text-js) a try. It can do things like auto link @mentions, #hashtags, and urls.

```
twttr.txt.autoLink('A @screen_name, #hashtag, and url: http://twitter.com autolinked')
```

Will result in:

```
"A @<a class="tweet-url username" data-screen-name="screen_name" href="http://twitter.com/screen_name" rel="nofollow">screen_name</a>, <a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23hashtag" title="#hashtag" class="tweet-url hashtag" rel="nofollow">#hashtag</a>, and url: <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow" >http://twitter.com</a> autolinked"
```

Or finding the indices of #hashtags:

```
twttr.txt.extractHashtagsWithIndices('A @screen_name, #hashtag, and url: http://twitter.com autolinked')
```

will result in:

```
[{
  hashtag: "hashtag",
  indices: [ 16, 24 ]
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to match a part of the string

```
hashtags = /\#\w+/g.exec( "The quick #brown fox" );
```

See it working at https://regex101.com/r/pai19N/1

Comment: thanks so much, although when running it through jQuery it only picks up the first one, even if there are more hashtags in the "string" any idea why?

Comment: You'll need to call exec multiple times to get all the matches.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript's .search() method will give you the index in a string that your character occurs:

```
<p id="mystring">Hello, how are #you today?</p>

alert($("#mystring").html().search("#"));
```

Comment: I think the downvote requires an explanation.  I tried his code out and it works flawlessly.